# Confusion about creating Page Types in Composite C1

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

Running Composite C1 4.2 Update 1

I'm trying to create a Page Type for our landing pages.  I want to specify a Layout as well as a Data Folder I designed for my new Page Type.  I'm able to create the Page Type without issue, then I right click and edit the Page Type.  I specified the Name, Description, Data Folder, and Layout and then try to click Save.  At this point it complains that I haven't specified an Application with a stop hand icon and "Selection Required" text.  I am following along with the Page Type manual I found here:

http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Page-Types/Adding-Applications#_Adding_Applications

From what I can tell it doesn't appear that an application should be required to create a Page Type. Am I missing something?

As a side note, if I do select an Application I am able to save and use the Page Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there was an issue in this version of Composite C1.

This issue will be fixed in the upcoming version 4.3 (release candidate now).

For the time being, a patch has been made to handle this bug. You can install it from the C1 Console:

System / Packages / Available Packages / Composite.Updates / Composite.Updates.Composite42Update1PatchForSelectors

Please also see http://compositec1.codeplex.com/workitem/2073

Comment: Installed the patch and it works perfectly.  Thanks for the continued assistance with Composite wysocki!